# PHP IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2)

Tags: php, exchange-server, imap

I'm using this library for reading mails: https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap

When trying to get all mails from mailbox (`$mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL');`) I got this error:

```
Caught exception: Connection error: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) Notice: Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

**Mailbox is on Microsoft Exchange Server**.
P.S. this solution don't help: [PHP IMAP Exchange Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815183/php-imap-exchange-issue)

Answer (score 1):

As Per Answer [Reading mails on server with IMAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830680/reading-mails-on-server-with-imap)

> I had exactly the same problem on my Ubuntu 11.04 system, and I've
>   solved by creating the "Maildir" folders in my home directory (as
>   described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Courier/)) with the following commands:
>
> ```
> cd ~
> maildirmake Maildir
> maildirmake Maildir/.Drafts
> maildirmake Maildir/.Sent
> maildirmake Maildir/.Trash
> maildirmake Maildir/.Templates
> chmod -R 700 Maildir
> ```
>
> First of all, you should check for errors in the log file
>   "/var/log/syslog" (for example by executing the command `sudo tail
>   /var/log/syslog`).
>  In my log I had noticed the following error:
>   `imapd: chdir Maildir: No such file or directory`.
>  So I've checked
>   the configuration file "/etc/courier/imapd" and I saw that the
>   MAILDIRPATH option was set to "Maildir":
>
> ```
> #
> # MAILDIRPATH - directory name of the maildir directory.
> #
> MAILDIRPATH=Maildir
> ```
>
> Then I've created the "Maildir" folders as described above, and the
>   "imap_open()" function finally worked.

Comment: My script is not on the same server, and I don't have imapd, script tries to connect to MS exchange server.